# Javascript for loop scope takes last variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
  var toggler = function(most){
    var open = $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').is(':visible');

    if(open){
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').hide();
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .plus').show();
    }else{
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .plus').hide();
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').show();
    }

    $('#' + most + ' ol.tlist').toggle(open);
  };

  $('#toggle_mostviewed').click(function(){ toggler('mostviewed'); });
  $('#toggle_mostshared').click(function(){ toggler('mostshared'); });
  $('#toggle_mostrecent').click(function(){ toggler('mostrecent'); });
```

But this does not:

```
  var toggler = function(most){
    var open = $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').is(':visible');

    if(open){
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').hide();
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .plus').show();
    }else{
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .plus').hide();
      $('#toggle_' + most + ' .minus').show();
    }

    $('#' + most + ' ol.tlist').toggle(open);
  };

  var t = ['mostviewed','mostshared','mostrecent'];
  for(var i = 0 ; i  < t.length; i++ ){
    var j = t[i];
    $('#toggle_' + j).click(function(){ toggler(j) });
  }
```

Is like the for loop was "replaced" by:

```
  $('#toggle_mostrecent').click(function(){ toggler('mostrecent'); });
```

i.e. the last iteration is the only that counts.

Comment: Closure issue. Google closure for loop. Need to wrap the loop logic in anonymous function.

Comment: Also a variable hoisting misunderstanding. Loop blocks don't get a scope in javascript -- unlike some other languages. That `var j` isn't where you think it is

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is constructed incorrectly. When you want to set a variable in a loop to access an element of an array or object, this is the correct syntax:

```
var test = [];
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; test++)
    (function(index){
        // do cool stuff with test[index]
    })(i);
```

This creates a closure over the variable i. If you aren't familiar with the syntax, here's what happens:

1) We define a closure (the opening ()'s after the for statement)

2) We define an anonymous function to take the index parameter

3) We pass the index into the closure (i.e. we execute the function)with the final set of ()'s.

These three steps happen for every iteration of the loop. If you don't use the closure to capture the index value, then when the array access is actually made, the index in this example would be +1 too many, and cause errors at runtime.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for, are there another ways to handle with this case?

Answer (score 0):

it is because of wrong use of a [closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

In this case since you are iterating through an array, you can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var t = ['mostviewed','mostshared','mostrecent'];
$.each(t, function(_,most){
    $('#toggle_' + most).click(function(){ toggler(most) });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

`$('#toggle_' + most).click(function(){ toggler(most) });`

but I think this is what you meant:

`$('#toggle_' + j).click(function(){ toggler(j) });`

(you defined `j` but then used `most` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
$('#toggle_mostviewed, #toggle_mostshared, #toggle_mostrecent').click(function({
    toggler((this.id).split("_").pop()); 
});
```

Or even better, give them a class "toggle" (and also leave the IDs in the html) and then:

```
$('.toggle').click(function({
    toggler((this.id).split("_").pop()); 
});
```