# Multiple fadeToggle()'s in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "projects" object. Each project has a div and another div inside it, which is hidden. I want to create multiple fadeToggle() effects, so that for each project - clicking the first div will make the one inside it show up.

I tried to do this with a simple for loop.

```
projects.display = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; ++i) {
    var projectID = "#projects-" + i;
    var moreInfoID = "#projects-" + i + "-more";

    // assign IDs for current project

    $(projectID).click(function() {
            $(moreInfoID).fadeToggle();
    });     
}};
```

The result of this code is that clicking any of the main div's triggers the hidden div of the LAST project to show up.

How can I make it so that clicking a main div will call fadeToggle() for the designated hidden div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not believe `for` loop is necessary. You should be able to substitute attribute starts with and attribute ends with selectors, `:has()` or `:not()`

```
$("[id^=projects]:has([id$=more])").click(function() {
  $("[id$=more]", this).fadeToggle()
})
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871627/javascript-for-loop-scope-takes-last-variable

Comment: Thank you! The linked question explained things perfectly and solved my problem.